# How do I automate this chrome tab with a proxy instead of using my own IP everytime

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

## Like if I had a list of proxies how can I incorporate it to open the tab with it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QggJzZdIYPI&ab_channel=CandRfun')
```

#using this link as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The just replace the ip of your proxy and port with desired ip and desired port in 2nd line.

```
from selenium import webdriver
    PROXY = "The desired IP:Desired port"
    chrome_options = WebDriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    chrome.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QggJzZdIYPI&ab_channel=CandRfun")
```